# How to fix non spacing issue for flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a basic web page that changes form based on the amount of pixels. If it's larger than 490, it uses a grid. If it's less, it uses a flex. The grid is working fine, however the flex will not put any space in between the cards I'm creating.

I've read over the w3schools article on Flexbox (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and have tried justify-content, which will center, but not space, and align-items, which makes the cards significantly thinner and provides no spacing. I've also tried playing around with different margins.

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head lang="en-us">
        <title>Final Frontier</title>
        <link href="css/mockup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/final-frontier.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>Final Frontier</h1>
        <form>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="search">
                <button type="button">
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </form><br>
        </center>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="card">Hello</div>        
            <div class="card">Hello</div>     
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div> 
            <div class="card">Hello</div>
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>      
            <div class="card">Hello</div>
            <div class="card">Hello</div>            


        <script src="js/final-frontier.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
    background-color: orange;
    height: 300px;
    /*margin-bottom: 20px;
    /*margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 50px;
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 490px){
     .container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center
     }    
}
```

Currently, the cards are aligned like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwRTw.png however there needs to be about 50px of spacing between each card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to manually set the margin-bottom like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px){
 .container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
 }    

 .container .card {
       margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
}
```